# My keyboard Num Lock button is missing

Tags: keyboard

I have an [**HP K3510 Wireless Keyboard**](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04852491) and it does not appear to have a <kbd>**`Num Lock`**</kbd> key on it even though it has a number pad area with the numeric characters?

[image]

Comment: Numlock is used to differentiate dual meanings of the number pad keys.  On your keyboard, those are dedicated keys.  There's no need for num lock.

Comment: @fixer1234: I'm not sure that's true.  On my (Dell) keyboard, the numeric pad keys look like the ones in the OP's picture — they have nothing printed on them except for the numerals "0" through "9".  But, if I press and hold "Shift", or press and release "Num Lock", my numeric pad keys become Home, End, PgUp, PgDn, and cursor (direction) keys — even though I have eight other keys dedicated to those functions.

Comment: @Scott, the question was why the num lock key was missing on that keyboard.  The fact that those, apparently dedicated, keys can be switched to a  secondary meaning could be a non-obvious feature or vestigial function.  Since there are dedicated keys for both of the number pad functions, HP could have figured that num lock was a dispensable key when figuring out how to fit all the keys on the available real estate.

Comment: probably the only way is autohotkey

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear exactly what your question is, or what you have tried. 
For example, what happens if you type on your numeric keypad
while holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key? 
Do they act like Home, End, PgUp, PgDn, and cursor (direction) keys then?

If your numeric keypad keys are dual-function,
and you want to use the navigation functions of those keys
without holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>,
or if you find them generating the navigation key keycodes by default
(and you want to switch it back to normal),
and you’re running Windows, try this advice [offered by HP](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02765720):

1. Run the On-Screen Keyboard program. 
   There are several ways you can do this:

   - Click on “Start”, type “on-screen”,
     and when “On-Screen Keyboard” appears, click on it.
   - Click on “Start” and navigate to “On-Screen Keyboard”
     (on my Windows 7 machine,
     it is under “All Programs” → “Accessories” → “Ease of Use”), and click on it.
   - Click on “Start”, click on “Run…” (if you have it on your Start Menu),
     and type “osk” (and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
   - Press <kbd>[image] (Windows)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,
     and type “osk” (and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
   - etc.
2. Then,

   - If your On-Screen Keyboard has a “Num Lock” on-screen key, click on it.
   - Otherwise, or if that doesn’t work,
     click on “Options”, “Turn on numeric keypad”, “OK”, and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

As you see on the numpad keys, there are no alternative function for each key, such as <kbd>Home</kbd> or arrow keys. This is no problem as you already have dedicated keys for that.

On my own laptop keyboard, I have both but for some reason they chose to remove it from yours, which in my personal opinion looks more elegant. Nobody ever uses the alternative functions of the numpad anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I bought same keyboard and have been looking for a solution for a while but there is non.

For the guys who doesn't understand what the problem is, the people who wants compact keyboard usually expects the number key pad does dual functionality with 'NumLock' toggle key.

Also, pressing shift key to activate the dual function doesn't help that much because it's not possible to enter combination of keys that text editor or office programs supports like 'control-shift-home'.

The 'dedicated function key' on the keyboard is not on standard location and users who use  more than 2 keyboard will get confused very easily. So, this keyboard layout is useless if there is no 'Num Lock' key.

Anyway, who does need dedicated 'Paste' key instead of pressing Ctrl-V ? I guess the HP keyboard designer does a lot of 'paste' instead of typing something useful.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: David, it's an answer. Simply, there is no way to make the numlock off for the keyboard. The other answers that I already tried doesn't work. Especially in windows 10 environment.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue with this model keyboard. Why in the world would they map a full numberpad, but not give the ability to toggle it? `</rant>`

In my google searches, I found [this support post](https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/ht501660-how-to-input-a-number-when-keyboard-has-no-numlock-numeric-lock-key-thinkpad-windows) for Lenovo. This suggests using the on-screen keyboard, which doesn't show the number pad section by default.

Press `Win`+`Ctrl`+`O` to open the on-screen keyboard. To enable the number pad, click on Options (bottom row, lower right). This will bring up an options dialog box. Check Turn on numeric key pad.

Once enabled, the numlock key will be on the bottom right.

For Linux, check out `numlockx` or [this Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Activating_numlock_on_bootup) for several methods.